# How to connect websocket and subscribe channels using unificationengine?

Tags: unificationengine

How to connect a websocket and subscribe channels for a user using *unificationengine*?

Answer (score 1):

The following command wss://USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET@apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/ws/start
    will start websocket and subscribe channels for the connectors (like sms, whatsapp, viber etc) which has push capability.